# document.write or Jquery Append doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I feel a bit silly for asking such a simple question but I've got a basic document.write that prints a form within a for loop so that jquery can be used to increase the number of times the form is printed. This works fine and as expected in all browsers apart from the i.e versions before i.e 11. Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Thanks

```
var limit = 1;
$('input[name=limit]').val(limit);
function addQuestion() {
    limit++; 
    $("#inputFields").append("Question "+limit+":<input type='text' name='Question"+limit+"' /><br />A.<input type='text' name='Q"+limit+"A' class='A'><input type='radio' name='Q"+limit+"correct' value='A' onclick='change1()'><br>B.<input type='text' name='Q"+limit+"B' class='B'><input type='radio' name='Q"+limit+"correct' value='B' onclick='change2()'><br>C.<input type='text' name='Q"+limit+"C' class='C'><input type='radio' name='Q"+limit+"correct' value='C' onclick='change3()'><br>D.<input type='text' name='Q"+limit+"D' class='D'><input type='radio' name='Q"+limit+"correct' value='D' onclick='change4()'><br>");
    $('input[name=limit]').val(limit);
}

for(var  i=1; i <= limit; i++) {    
    document.write("Question "+i+":<input type='text' name='Question"+i+"'><br>A.<input type='text' name='Q"+i+"A' class='"+i+"A'><input type='radio' name='Q"+i+"correct' value='A' onclick='change1("+i+")'><br>B.<input type='text' name='Q"+i+"B' class='"+i+"B'><input type='radio' name='Q"+i+"correct' value='B' onclick='change2("+i+")'><br>C.<input type='text' name='Q"+i+"C' class='"+i+"C'><input type='radio' name='Q"+i+"correct' value='C' onclick='change3("+i+")'><br>D.<input type='text' name='Q"+i+"D' class='"+i+"D'><input type='radio' name='Q"+i+"correct' value='D' onclick='change4("+i+")'><br>");
}
```

Comment: This works fine for me on IE9. I've created a JSFiddle for your question http://jsfiddle.net/5fsC6/

Comment: @heymega I've used IE9 as well and it doesn't for me. Is it possible that a secutiry feature is blocking the script?

Comment: do you get errors in the console? what does the rest of the code look like (could you perhaps create a complete [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))?

Comment: @Raidri I will create a jsfiddle in a sec. But the only consol error I'm getting is SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined

Comment: do you load `jquery.js` before your script? it seems that is the problem.

Comment: This is used in the head section to load it: 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

Comment: I'm also getting this error in the consol: SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: Add `http://` in your script source .Try doing this `src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"`. May have to do something with Cross Origin Security.

Comment: Youre right. Adding http:// will fix the issue but its not cross origin security its probably because the user is running this locally on their machine

Comment: @heymega: Yes, the the file requesting this JS is in different domain as that where the JS is actually hosted.

Comment: I've added it and it has made no difference: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

Comment: Well either your script isnt getting ran or its getting ran after your custom script. Try and gives us your complete code. It might be worth trying to save js locally and reference it that way

Comment: Check if JS has been disabled in IE and also try clearing your Browser cache once. To add to this, also see if you are running in compatibilty mode or browser mode.

Comment: The trouble with giving the rest of the code is it s about 700 lines of php that I'm fairly certain is not relevent to this javascript which is the only js script I am running. And I've cleared the cache and I've been running in compbatability and normal 9 mode and it still has no effect.